# Is there any way to get rid of the background of a highlighted item from a xamarin forms list view?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using a list view to presenting some items but I don't want any background of any kind. Since I'm using SelectionMode="None", the tap event is not marking the item, but a gray background appears and goes away, what gives an idea of something selectable, which is not. I was using collection view but has moved to list due to performing problems(jitter) while scrolling, so move to collection is not a solution.

I already tried:

- trigger - setting background color view cell to none
- I've changed android styles:
  `<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>`

I didn't test it on ios yet but I have to take this off from there also. 
Does any one knows if it's possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use custom renderer to get rid of the gray background, let me show you the code:

A simple listView:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <ListView SelectionMode="None"  ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>mono</x:String>
                <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

In Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ListView), typeof(DisplayOnlyListViewRenderer))]
namespace App277.Droid
{
    // DISABLES LISTVIEW ROW HIGHLIGHT
    [Obsolete]
    public class DisplayOnlyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
                Control.CacheColorHint = Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In iOS project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(NativeViewCellRenderer))]
namespace App277.iOS
{
    public class NativeViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

            // removes default selection style (gray background color on tapped event)
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

I have uploaded my demo [here](https://github.com/XfHua/ListView-Remove-Selected-gray-color) and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: It works. And it's an amazing and simple solution! Thanks in advance, Jack.

Comment: is there a way to use this only with a specific list view? and let others with the normal behavior?

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra Yes, use a custom listView/View cell in shared project and change the `Xamarin.forms.listView` to `ExportRenderer(typeof(yourCustomListView)` or `ExportRenderer(typeof(yourCustomViewCell)`.

Comment: Nice, Jack. Thank you